# Calling a formula an equation in "How to Format"

Tags: bug, editing, user-interface

I am not sure if this is SE-wide.  I do not see it on [MO](http://mathoverflow.net) or [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com).  When I try to edit a post on MESE, I see:

[image: Editing instructions]

However, $\sin^2 \theta$ is a formula, not an equation.  On a general site this is maybe not worth fixing, but, in a site whose audience has a built-in interest in mathematics, it might be worth the hopefully small trouble of getting it right.

Comment: The original fault may lie with $\LaTeX$ and its "equation" environment, e.g. "\begin{equation}". Or maybe it goes back farther than that. In mathematical typesetting we say "equation number" even for a number attached to an inequality or other type of non-equation.

Comment: @WillOrrick, [that](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/calling-a-formula-an-equation-in-how-to-format#comment2063_756) point is well taken, and these terms are not great either.  If this is not implemented for a reason other than "it would be very hard to do so" or "the moderators don't care", then I expect something like that to be the reason.  But, of course, the existence of bad terminology for historical reasons doesn't mean it has to be propagated.